# How to rename files using the Google drive API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api

Using Rails 5 with Google::Apis::DriveV2, I'm trying to rename a file:

In the gem file, I had google-api-client and Devise

```
gem 'google-api-client'
gem 'devise
```

I configure Drive service like that (inside a initializer file):

```
Drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2::DriveService.new
```

Inside my controler , I do

```
file = Drive.copy_file("id_of_the_template")

# first try to rename
Drive.patch_file(file.id,"body"=>{"title"=>"New_Name"})

# second try to rename
project_slide.title = "New_Name"
project_slide.update!
```

The file is perfectly duplicated but the first and the second try doesn't rename the file.

Previously I try:

```
Drive.patch_file(file.id,"body"=>{"title"=>"New_Name"})
```

I got this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `rename' for #<Google::Apis::DriveV2::File:0x007f9e06809fe8>):
```

I spent hours looking to find a working method but didn't find it and am quite lost in the Google documentation. 
Here the documentation that I have read:

- https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/ruby
- http://www.rubydoc.info/github/gimite/google-drive-ruby/GoogleDrive%2FFile%3Arename
- http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/DriveV2/File#update!-instance_method
- http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google%2FApis%2FDriveV2%2FDriveService%3Apatch_file
- https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch

Comment: Please explain what part of the documentation didn't make sense; We can help clarify it. What does "renaming doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error when renaming the file? Does it silently fail? Does the code run without complaining but the file isn't renamed? Please read "[mcve]" and the linked pages.

Comment: make sure you aren't mixing v2 and v3. Your code references Google::Apis::DriveV2 but the quickstart you point to uses v3.

Comment: Can only agree. Renaming a file doesn't work in v3. I've also tried project_slide.update!(name: 'New_name') and that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Nello. I finally create a webservice with google script API, ...and its work.   `var model_file = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
  var fichier_Document = model_file.makeCopy(documentNewName);`